# Interacting with elements within nested iFrames, Existing on page but returning null

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

I am programming a script that will download a report for me. One of my steps involves checking a table for the correct date of the report I want to pull. The website im working on is old, and they are set up using multiple iFrames (they are of the same domain).

From my research, ive come up with this line to return the innerText of a certain row in a table

```
document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.document.getElementById('iframe2').contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('status_table')[5].innerText
```

iFrame2 contains the table with all the info I want to access. This line works, but only sometimes. When I refresh the page, wait 10 seconds, and run the command, it returns null. It seems after I expand all the elements in google chrome, or mess around with the page a bit it starts working and returning the correct information.

Im not sure what is going on here, am I accessing the elements wrong? Why does it start working after I click things on the page or after I expand the elements in the dev console? Any Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, When I use getElementsByTagName instead of getElementByID It works all the time!

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[2].contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('status_table')[5].innerText.toString();
```